# SET text property of a span element in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

On post request, this code checks if the date input field given on a form contains today's date. If so, the `span` element placed next to the date input field must display an error message. My work is as following

```js
$('.submit-btn').click(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  var month = d.getMonth();
  var month_actual = month + 1;
  if (month_actual < 10) {
    month_actual = "0" + month_actual;
  }
  var day_val = d.getDate();
  if (day_val < 10) {
    day_val = "0" + day_val;
  }
  if ($('input[type="date"]').val() == d.getFullYear() + "-" + month_actual + "-" + day_val) {
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("name");
    $('.text-danger-' + inputValue).text("This date is incorrect");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input asp-for="@Model.DateOfBirth" class="form-control" type="date" name="inputDateOfBirth" />
<span class="text-danger-inputDateOfBirth"></span>
<button class="submit-btn">Submit</button>
```

`span` is not showing the error-message text (This date is incorrect).

Comment: if you really want that js to do what you expect you should add `name="inputDateOfBirth"` to the submit button. Why did you use the name attribute to fetch the corresponding element via class selector and then didn't populate the name attribute of the button? By the way there are some potential problems in such logic.. maybe you should prefer the onsubmit event of the parent form to perform such an action? and are you aware that such logic won't prevent the form to be submitted (if any)?

Comment: Here are steps I use to debug these types of things. 1) Put `console.log("test")` into the IF statement to make sure it is returning true / false correctly. 2) If you are not getting the `test` string in the console, log out what the values of the input and the current date are and see where the differences may be. *this could be date format*. Check that the `text-danger-inputDateOfBirth` doesn't apply `display: none` or invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in the context where you used it was the button and it had no name. Fixed version:

```js
$('.submit-btn').click(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  var month = d.getMonth();
  var month_actual = month + 1;
  if (month_actual < 10) {
    month_actual = "0" + month_actual;
  }
  var day_val = d.getDate();
  if (day_val < 10) {
    day_val = "0" + day_val;
  }
  let myDate = $('input[type=date]');
  var inputValue = myDate.attr("name");
  if (myDate.val() == (d.getFullYear() + "-" + month_actual + "-" + day_val)) {
    $('.text-danger-' + inputValue).text("This date is incorrect");
  } else {
    $('.text-danger-' + inputValue).text("");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input asp-for="@Model.DateOfBirth" class="form-control" type="date" name="inputDateOfBirth" />
<span class="text-danger-inputDateOfBirth"></span>
<button class="submit-btn">Submit</button>
```

Comment: The conditional was correct.

Comment: @connexo thanks for pointing this out, I was misreading the question. Edited the answer.

Comment: Now except fixing the code (which is trivial once understood) your answer doesn't add anything which my answer didn't already do, right?

Comment: The initial error involving the `this` is fixed in the snippet. However, the above snippet will not behave in a reasonable way when a "wrong" date was entered, checked by clicking "Submit" and was then corrected and checked again. In this case the error message will not disappear.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann thanks for pointing it out. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @connexo I have started writing my answer before you sent yours. The difference between our approaches was that I tested my answer, whereas you have written suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
$(this).attr("name");
```

`this` is pointing to the `button` - which doesn't have a `name` - not the `input` (which you wanted).

So

```
$('.text-danger-' + inputValue)
```

will actually be

```
$('.text-danger-')
```

which won't find an element, thus it cannot set the text.

Had you not used jQuery you'd have found an error in the console helping you, namely `cannot access property "text" of null`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you wanted to achieve with your snippet, but you used the wrong `this` inside your function, as it will point to the button element and not the input element with the `value` inside. Your addressing mechanism involving the `name` attribute and creating a class name out of it seems overly complicated. The snippet below addresses the elements n a *relative* way through the jQuery `.prev()` method:

```js
$('.submit-btn').click(function() {
  const d=new Date(), $span=$(this).prev("span");
  $span.text($span.prev("input").val()==(d.getFullYear()+"-"+String(d.getMonth()+1).padStart(2,"0")
    +"-"+String(d.getDate()).padStart(2,"0"))?"The date is right":"You got the wrong date!")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input asp-for="@Model.DateOfBirth" class="form-control" type="date">
<span></span>
<button class="submit-btn">Submit</button><br>
<input asp-for="@Model.somethingElse" class="form-control" type="date">
<span></span>
<button class="submit-btn">Submit</button>
```

(( The above snippet contains two groups of input and button elements to demonstrate the *relative DOM element selection* with `$(this).prev()`. ))